# How to resize master/detail views of sap.m.SplitApp?

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to enable user to slide vertical border and to resize master/detail views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is currently not supported.

The only way to achieve something like this is to use [sap.ui.layout.Splitter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.layout.Splitter/samples) and responsive layouts in it.